# Why don't I have touchscreen support in Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to create a new AVD with touchscreen support, but there are none in the hardware specification option. I search the web and I found out that when I try to create a new AVD I should have the option to add new hardware. Why don't I have this option? I've downloaded the SDK and I've installed the Android 2.3 API and all the extra packages. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

All AVDs have touchscreen support. I see no option to *block* touchscreen support.

Comment: Here's what I get: [link](http://cdn.imghack.se/images/ea33865f6e0ef7c3573923d3971ae9f6.png)

Comment: @user1956096: What is your evidence that your AVD does not have a touchscreen?

Comment: Do they all have audio output enabled? I just ran one and it doesn't seem to have an audio output

Comment: @user1956096: AFAIK, all AVDs support audio output. Whether the *emulator* and your OS cooperate for audio output may vary. For example, I used to have some problems with running the emulator on Linux and getting audio output, though that has not been an issue for me since 2009.

Comment: @user1956096: Post a new question on StackOverflow. Explain your *precise* and *complete* setup, including development machine OS/version, Android tools version, and AVD version. Also explain how you are testing your audio output. With luck, somebody will be able to assist you.

Comment: Thx you've been helpful enough :)